# iPhone: hide address bar, also if user clicks top of screen or clock/battery bar

Tags: iphone

I want the address bar to disappear on the iPhone. So far I have used:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

This hides the address bar when the page is first loaded.

Then I have

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

This prevents the user from scrolling back up to the address bar (or anywhere else) while still allowing buttons to be tapped.

But, the address bar still appears when I tap the top of the page. Not sure if this is because I am touching the top of the webpage or because I am touching the bar with the clock and battery.

I'm guessing that the user himself would need to set this option on his phone, although it would be nice if I could control it via the webpage. Is either way possible?

Why? I want to make a web app for a disabled child who has a hard time controlling his movements. I essentially want to turn off any touch actions that aren't related to the web app itself. Otherwise he will accidentally set off lots of unwanted actions. Not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't hide the status bar. For example in iOS 6 you can, in landscape mode, go full screen, it hides the status bar, but there is a new button at the bottom right of the screen to leave the full screen mode.

What you are asking is not achievable within Safari. But you can develop a simple application full screen (no adress bar, no buttons, no status bar) with a simple `UIWebView`. This way there will not be any unwanted action.